# suggesting the correct approach with respect to multiple conditions

Tags: java

I was advising one of my friend to not to add logger with single if condition. If there were multiple lines after the if clause then It will treated as sonar critical issue

below is the wrong use

Ex: (Single if clause – Sonar critical issue) :  Only the first line will be executed conditionally.  The rest will execute unconditionally.

```
//Some Code
if(logger.isInfoEnabled())
logger.info("Entering " + CLASS_NAME + " Method : generateGSTR2PreviewPDF");
//Some Code
```

so i have suggested them two approaches , please advise any better approach is still there apart which i advise .

my suggested approaches shown below are

first one is

Approach 1: (Adding a flower bracket) :

```
    //Some Code
    if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){
    logger.info("Entering " + CLASS_NAME + " Method : generateGSTR2PreviewPDF");
    }
    //Some Code
```

and the second one is

Approach 2 : (Segregating it through separate method):

```
//Some Code
addLogger("Entering " + CLASS_NAME + " Method : generateGSTR2PreviewPDF");
//Some Code
```

Please advise is there any better approach apart from these two.

Answer (score 0):

The first with `if {}`.

The guard (if-statement) is done to prevent too much work (when logging is disabled on INFO level), an optimisation (here string concatenation and maybe toString calls). Calling a function negates this optimisation.

In fact instead of the second case you could just drop the entire if-guard and just call `logger.info`.

In the case above I might have done just that.